# toMatch Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing

Does anyone know why this isn't passing?

```
function correctColorDisplay(message, player_turn, selector) {
  if ((message > 0) && (player_turn != 0)) {
    return $(selector).append("<li>" + message + " " + "color(s) are present but not in the correct position in Round " + player_turn + ".</li>");
  }
}
```

Jasmine:

```
describe('#correctColorDisplay', function(){
  it('returns a message to the user displaying if a correct color (not positions) was chosen', function(){
    var message = 2
    var playerTurn = 2
    var selector = $('<li></li>')
    correctColorDisplay(message,playerTurn, selector)
    expect(selector).toMatch("<li>" + message + " " + "color(s) are present but not in the correct position in Round " + playerTurn + ".</li>")
  });
});
```

The error I keep getting is this giant message: Expected { 0 : HTMLNode, length : 1, jquery : '1.11.0', constructor : Function, selector : '', toArray : Function, get : Function, pushStack : Function, each, etc (it goes on much longer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to match a newly created HTMLNode with a regular expression (that is basically just a string in this case).

The `toMatch` function of Jasmine is for regular expressions.

I'm not entirely familiar with Jasmine, but I'm guessing you're looking for something like:

```
describe('#correctColorDisplay', function(){
    it('returns a message to the user displaying if a correct color (not positions) was chosen', function() {
        var message = 2;
        var playerTurn = 2;
        var selector = $('<li></li>');
        selector = correctColorDisplay(message, playerTurn, selector);
        expect(selector).toEqual( $("<li><li>" + message + " " + "color(s) are present but not in the correct position in Round " + playerTurn + ".</li></li>") );
    });
});
```

If that doesn't work, I suggest you look into [jasmine-jquery](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery/).

Comment: Thanks Reaxis. I actually tried toEqual as well and it displays the same messsage. I also tried toHaveText in the jasmine-jquery library and had no luck with that either. I think my whole set up is wrong.

Comment: I don't think your whole setup is necessarily wrong, just the Jasmine comparison. If you want to test the text content of the node you can use `expect(selector.text()).toEqual( $("<li><li>" + message + " " + "color(s) are present but not in the correct position in Round " + playerTurn + ".</li></li>").text() );`

Comment: ahhh perfect. I just tried this (with the .text()) and it worked exactly how I wanted to. Thanks for the help!